# How do you create an entity using an api call in DialogFlow [formerly api.ai]

Tags: entities, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a chatbot in DialogueFlow. In the docs it says

> You can create your own entities for your agents, either through web forms, uploading them in JSON or CSV formats, or **via API calls.**

How do I create an entity using an API call?

Answer (score 1):

Send a POST request! Dialogflow has good REST endpoints.

```
curl -X POST \
'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/entities?v=20150910' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "entries": [{
      "synonyms": ["apple", "red apple"],
      "value": "apple"
    },
    {
      "value": "banana"
    }
  ],
  "name": "fruit"
}'
```

From the [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#post_entities).

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly what I was looking for.

But I've just spent a couple of hours googling trying to discover how can I send this curl POST and unfortunately I didn't find nothing that can help me.

If someone can give a light here I be very happy.

Some details:

1. I communicate with my chatbot throw a python Flask server, this means that I am using the python SDK.
2. In which part of the code in the server should I make this request?

Here is the solution that I found:

```
import os.path
import sys
import requests
import json

DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your developer token'

def sending_entities():
   # 1 DEFINE THE URL
   url = 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/entities?v=20150910'

   # 2 DEFINE THE HEADERS    
   headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+DEVELOPER_ACCESS_TOKEN,'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

   # 3 CREATE THE DATA
   data = json.dumps({
     "name": "fruit",
     "entries": [
     {
       "synonyms": ["apple", "red apple"],
       "value": "apple"
     },
     {
       "value": "banana"
     }
   ]
  })

  # 4 MAKE THE REQUEST 
  response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
  print (response.json)
```